# How to solve this integral using some special functions? $I=\int_a^b \frac{\sin u}{(c-u-\sin u)^{2/3}}du$

Tags: definite-integrals, special-functions, gamma-function, hypergeometric-function, elliptic-functions

This integral cannot be solved with any standard function

$$I=\int_a^b \frac{\sin u}{(c-u-\sin u)^{2/3}}du$$

$c,a,b\in \mathbb{R}^+\;\;,\;\;c>u+\sin u \, \forall\;u\in[a,b]$

It is possible to solve this integral using any Special Functions ( Elliptic Integrals, Hypergeometric Functions, Gamma function etc..)?

Comment: Mathematica balks at it. You might try differentiation under the integral sign, but there's a lot of different avenues there.

Comment: If you mean integration by parts, yes, it doesn't change much

Comment: What is meant by "differentiation under the integral" is the use of the formula $$\frac{d}{dt}\int_{x_1}^{x_2}f(t,x)dx=\int_{x_1}^{x_2}\frac{\partial}{\partial t}f(t,x)dx$$ where $x_1,x_2$ are constants in terms of $t$.

Comment: What would it be the use of "differentiation under the integral"  for solving this integral? The function in the integral is only function of u

Comment: @C.C.12 One often introduces a new parameter with respect to which to differentiate.

Comment: @MathlsFun7225   I'm sorry, but I don't think I understood. Could you give me an example please? Even on this specific case maybe

Comment: @C.C.12 see my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2726646/show-that-int-0-infty-frac-arctan-mathrm%cf%80x-arctan-mathrm-xxdx-fra/2726655#2726655)

Comment: @ mathworker21   Ah ok, the Feynman method ! But in this case,doing the calculations, it doesn't seem to me that it solves anything, or i am wrong?

Comment: I don;t think it's possible to express this in closed-form...

Comment: "The function in the integral is only function of u".  False.  The integrand is a function of $u$ and $c$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let
$\ v=c-u,$
then 
$$I=\int\limits_{c-b}^{c-a}\dfrac{\sin(c-v)\,\mathrm dv}{\sqrt[3]{(v-\sin(c-v))^2}}
 = \int\limits_{c-b}^{c-a}\dfrac{\sin(c-v)v^{\mathbf-{\large 2\over3}\,\mathrm dv}}{\left(1-\dfrac{\sin(c-v)}v\right)^{\large 2\over3}},$$
$$I = \int\limits_{c-b}^{c-a} S(c,v)\,\mathrm dv,\tag1$$
where
$$S(c,v) = \sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty(-1)^k\dbinom{-2/3}{k}\sin^{k+1}(c-v)\,v^{^{\Large -\frac{3k+2}3}},\tag2$$
$$\dbinom{-2/3}{k} = \dfrac1{k!}\dfrac{\Gamma\left(\dfrac13\right)}{\Gamma\left(\dfrac13-k\right)} = {(-1)}^k\cdot1\cdot\dfrac23\cdot\dfrac56\cdot\dfrac89\dots\dfrac{3k-1}{3k},\tag3$$

[image: Binom -2/3]

> $$2^{2m-1}\sin^{2m}x = \dfrac12\binom{2m}m + \sum\limits_{j=1}^{m}
> (-1)^j\dbinom{2m}{m-j}\cos 2jx\tag4$$
>   (see also [Wolfram Alpha test](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum_%7Bj%3D1%2C4%7D%20%28%28-1%29%5Ej%20binom%282*4%2C%204-j%29%20cos%282j%20x%29%29%20%2B%20binom%282*4%2C4%29%2F2)),
>   $$4^m\sin^{2m+1}x = \sum\limits_{j=0}^{m}(-1)^j\dbinom{2m+1}{m-j}\sin (2j+1)x \tag5$$
>   (see also [Wolfram Alpha test](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum_%7Bj%3D0%2C4%7D%20%28%28-1%29%5Ej%20binom%282*4%2B1%2C%204-j%29%20sin%28%282j%2B1%29%20x%29%29)).

Therefore,
$$S(c,v) = S_0(c,v)+S_1(c,v)+S_2(c,v),$$
where
\begin{align}
&S_0(c,v) = \sum\limits_{m=1}^\infty\dbinom{-2/3}{2m}4^{-m}\binom{2m}m\,v^{^{\Large -\frac{6m+2}3}},\\
&S_1(c,v) = \sum\limits_{m=1}^\infty\dbinom{-2/3}{2m}2^{-2m+1}\,v^{^{\Large -\frac{6m+2}3}}\sum\limits_{j=1}^{m}
(-1)^j\dbinom{2m}{m-j}\cos 2j(c-v)\\
&S_2(c,v) = - \sum\limits_{m=0}^\infty\dbinom{-2/3}{2m+1}4^{-m}\,v^{^{\Large -\frac{6m+5}3}}\sum\limits_{j=0}^{m}(-1)^j
\dbinom{2m+1}{m-j}\sin (2j+1)(c-v),\\
\end{align}

wherein
$$S_0(c,v) = \dfrac{_1F_2\left(\dfrac13,\dfrac56,1,\dfrac1{v^2}\right)-1}{v^{^{\Large -\frac{2}3}}},\tag6$$
(see also [Wolfram Alpha calculations](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum_%7Bm%3D1%2Cinfty%7D%20%28binom%28-2%2F3%2C2m%29%20*binom%282m%2Cm%29*v%5E%28-%286m%2B2%29%2F3%29%2F4%5Em%29)),
$$I_0(c,v) = \int S_0(c,v) dv = 3\sqrt[3]v \left(_2F_1\left(-\dfrac16,\dfrac13, 1, \dfrac1{v^2}\right) - 1\right) + \mathrm{constant}\tag7$$
(see also [Wolfram Alpha integration](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int%20%20%282F1%281%2F3%2C%205%2F6%2C%201%2C%201%2Fv%5E2%29%20-%201%29%2Fv%5E%282%2F3%29%29)).

Applying the exponent integral, one can get formulas for [the even factors](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int%20cos%28j%20%28c-v%29%29%20v%5E%28-%286m%2B2%29%2F3%29)

> $$\begin{align}
> &f_{m,j}(c,v) = \int \cos(2j(c-v))\, v^{\large- 2m-^2/_3}\,\mathrm dv = -\dfrac12 v^{\large - 2m+^1/_3}\\[4pt]
> & \times\left(e^{2ijc} \operatorname E^\,_{\large \,2m+^2/_3}(2ijv) + e^{-2ijc}\operatorname E^\,_{\large \,2m+^2/_3}(-2ijv)\right) +\mathrm{constant}
> \end{align}\tag8$$

and [for the odd factors](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int%20sin%28%282j%2B1%29%28c-v%29%29%20v%5E%28-%286m%2B5%29%2F3%29)

> $$\hspace{-30mu}\begin{align}
> &g_{m,j}(c,v)  = \int \sin((2j+1)(c-v))\, v^{\large -2m - ^5/_3}\,\mathrm dv
> = \dfrac i2 v^{\large -2m-^2/_3}\\[4pt]
> &\times\Bigg(e^{i(2j+1)c}\operatorname E^\,_{\large \,2m+^5/_3}(i(2j+1)v) - e^{-i(2j+1)c} \operatorname E^\,_{\large \,2m+^5/_3}(-i(2j+1)v)\Big) +\mathrm{constant}.
> \end{align}\tag9$$

Therefore, the solution is

$$
\begin{aligned}
&I= \left(I_0(c,v) + \sum\limits_{m=1}^\infty\dbinom{-2/3}{2m}2^{-2m+1}\,\sum\limits_{j=1}^{m}
(-1)^j\dbinom{2m}{m-j}f_{m,j}(c,v)\right. \\[4pt]
&\left. - \sum\limits_{m=0}^\infty\dbinom{-2/3}{2m+1}4^{-m}\,v^{^{\Large -\frac{6m+5}3}}\sum\limits_{j=0}^{m}(-1)^j
\dbinom{2m+1}{m-j}g_{m,j}(c,v)\right)_{c-b}^{c-a},
\end{aligned}\tag{10}
$$
where all used functions are defined by formulas $(7)-(9).$

[On the other hand](http://functions.wolfram.com/GammaBetaErf/ExpIntegralE/17/01/02/), the identity

> $$E_\nu(z) = \dfrac{z^n}{(1-\nu)_n}E_{\nu-n}(z) - e^{-z}\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1}\dfrac{z^k}{(1-\nu)_{k+1}}$$

allows to attack obtained result. However, all my attempts were unsuccessful.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, this is a prime step. Unfortunately, even after many attempts, I still could not find a definitive solution

Comment: @C.C.12 I'm trying to get more.

Comment: @C.C.12 This is maximum of possible for me.

Comment: @ Yuri Negometyanov  Very thanks for your efforts !

Comment: @C.C.12 However, your choice was 4D series instead 2D. ;)

Comment: @ Yuri Negometyanov Why?

Comment: @C.C.12 Sollution $(10)$ gives $2D$ series. I had tried to obtain $1D$ series, but it looks impossible.

Answer (score 2):

$\int_a^b\dfrac{\sin u}{(c-u-\sin u)^\frac{2}{3}}~du$

$=\int_a^b\dfrac{\sin u}{c^\frac{2}{3}\left(1-\dfrac{u+\sin u}{c}\right)^\frac{2}{3}}~du$

$=\int_a^b\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{\left(\dfrac{2}{3}\right)_n(u+\sin u)^n\sin u}{c^{n+\frac{2}{3}}n!}~du$ (according to http://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/Hypergeometric1F0/02)

$=\int_a^b\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\sum\limits_{m=0}^n\dfrac{\left(\dfrac{2}{3}\right)_nu^m\sin^{n-m+1}u}{c^{n+\frac{2}{3}}m!(n-m)!}~du$

$=\int_a^b\sum\limits_{m=0}^\infty\sum\limits_{n=m}^\infty\dfrac{\left(\dfrac{2}{3}\right)_nu^m\sin^{n-m+1}u}{c^{n+\frac{2}{3}}m!(n-m)!}~du$

$=\int_a^b\sum\limits_{m=0}^\infty\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{\left(\dfrac{2}{3}\right)_{m+n}u^m\sin^{n+1}u}{c^{m+n+\frac{2}{3}}m!n!}~du$

$=\int_a^b\sum\limits_{m=0}^\infty\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{\left(\dfrac{2}{3}\right)_{m+2n}u^m\sin^{2n+1}u}{c^{m+2n+\frac{2}{3}}m!(2n)!}~du+\int_a^b\sum\limits_{m=0}^\infty\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{\left(\dfrac{2}{3}\right)_{m+2n+1}u^m\sin^{2n+2}u}{c^{m+2n+\frac{5}{3}}m!(2n+1)!}~du$

$=\int_a^b\sum\limits_{m=0}^\infty\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\sum\limits_{p=0}^n\dfrac{\Gamma\left(m+2n+\dfrac{2}{3}\right)C_{n+p+1}^{2n+1}u^m\sin((2p+1)u)}{\Gamma\left(\dfrac{2}{3}\right)4^nc^{m+2n+\frac{2}{3}}m!(2n)!}~du+\int_a^b\sum\limits_{m=0}^\infty\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{\Gamma\left(m+2n+\dfrac{5}{3}\right)C_{n+1}^{2n+2}u^m}{\Gamma\left(\dfrac{2}{3}\right)4^{n+1}c^{m+2n+\frac{5}{3}}m!(2n+1)!}~du-\int_a^b\sum\limits_{m=0}^\infty\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\sum\limits_{p=0}^n\dfrac{\Gamma\left(m+2n+\dfrac{5}{3}\right)(-1)^pC_{n+p+2}^{2n+2}u^m\cos((2p+2)u)}{\Gamma\left(\dfrac{2}{3}\right)2^{2n+1}c^{m+2n+\frac{5}{3}}m!(2n+1)!}~du$

(according to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Power-reduction_formulae)

$=\int_a^b\sum\limits_{m=0}^\infty\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{\Gamma\left(m+2n+\dfrac{5}{3}\right)u^m}{\Gamma\left(\dfrac{2}{3}\right)2^{2n+1}c^{m+2n+\frac{5}{3}}m!n!(n+1)!}~du-\int_a^b\sum\limits_{m=0}^\infty\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\sum\limits_{p=0}^n\dfrac{\Gamma\left(m+2n+\dfrac{5}{3}\right)(-1)^p(n+1)u^m\cos((2p+2)u)}{\Gamma\left(\dfrac{2}{3}\right)4^nc^{m+2n+\frac{5}{3}}m!(n-p)!(n+p+2)!}~du+\int_a^b\sum\limits_{m=0}^\infty\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\sum\limits_{p=0}^n\dfrac{\Gamma\left(m+2n+\dfrac{2}{3}\right)(2n+1)u^m\sin((2p+1)u)}{\Gamma\left(\dfrac{2}{3}\right)4^nc^{m+2n+\frac{2}{3}}m!(n-p)!(n+p+1)!}~du$

$=\left[\sum\limits_{m=0}^\infty\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{\Gamma\left(m+2n+\dfrac{5}{3}\right)u^{m+1}}{\Gamma\left(\dfrac{2}{3}\right)2^{2n+1}c^{m+2n+\frac{5}{3}}(m+1)!n!(n+1)!}\right]_a^b-\left[\sum\limits_{m=0}^\infty\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\sum\limits_{p=0}^n\sum\limits_{q=0}^m\dfrac{\Gamma\left(m+2n+\dfrac{5}{3}\right)(-1)^p(n+1)u^{m-q}\sin\left((2p+2)u+\dfrac{q\pi}{2}\right)}{\Gamma\left(\dfrac{2}{3}\right)4^nc^{m+2n+\frac{5}{3}}(2p+2)^{q+1}(m-q)!(n-p)!(n+p+2)!}\right]_a^b-\left[\sum\limits_{m=0}^\infty\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\sum\limits_{p=0}^n\sum\limits_{q=0}^m\dfrac{\Gamma\left(m+2n+\dfrac{2}{3}\right)(2n+1)u^{m-q}\cos\left((2p+1)u+\dfrac{q\pi}{2}\right)}{\Gamma\left(\dfrac{2}{3}\right)4^nc^{m+2n+\frac{2}{3}}(2p+1)^{q+1}(m-q)!(n-p)!(n+p+1)!}\right]_a^b$

(according to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_integrals_of_trigonometric_functions)

Comment: This however does not solve the problem. The solution is still expressed in integral temrines and not in terms of any special function or definitive series